# Sound intensity and space/things in the way

Tags: acoustics, power

Suppose you have two stationary people, A and B, who are equally effective in terms of hearing ability, and A emits a sound that is heard by B at a certain intensity. If they remain stationary, and B makes the exact same sound, does A hear the sound at the same intensity as B?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both of them will hear the sound with same intensity. From your description, their situation are completely symmetric, so you can simply relabelled them from A to B, and B to A. Hence the results.

Comment: I don't think it's this obvious. The question doesn't say that their surroundings are symmetric, e.g. A could be standing next to a wall whereas B is in an open space.